# unable to publish mvc6 app due to invokepowershell failure in vs2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, powershell-3.0

I am having some serious grief trying to publish my mvc6 application due to a powershell file blockage. I ran powershell as an administrator and adjusted the execution policy. But it doesnt seem to have any impact on the publishing process in vs2015. Further to that i even tried in vain to run the Unblock-File cmdlet in the NPM.

Anyone have any ideas about how I can get this to work? the full error is below:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): Error MSB4018: The "InvokePowerShell" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: AuthorizationManager check failed. ---> System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run G:\_PIPELINE_MANAGEMENT\_SOURCE\_MANAGEMENT\_2016\ProjMgr\src\ProjMgr\Properties\PublishProfiles\ProjMgr-publish.ps1?
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.ThrowPromptNotInteractive(String promptMessage)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.PromptForChoice(String caption, String message, Collection`1 choices, Int32 defaultChoice)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.RemoteFilePrompt(String path, PSHost host)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.CheckPolicy(ExternalScriptInfo script, PSHost host, Exception& reason)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSAuthorizationManager.ShouldRun(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host, Exception& reason)
   at System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.InvokePowerShell.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
                Done executing task "InvokePowerShell" -- FAILED.
                Done building target "PowerShellPublish" in project "ProjMgr.xproj" -- FAILED.
        Done building project "ProjMgr.xproj" -- FAILED.
        Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED.
        Done building target "FileSystemPublish" in project "ProjMgr.xproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "ProjMgr.xproj" -- FAILED.

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
```

Comment: Try to run VS as administrator.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that was one of the first things i tried also

Answer (score 3):

Create another publish profile and try again.
For me this works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to publish by copying my entire project folder to the root of my local. Must be a folder permissions issue somewhere...